# Stop regex search on user request or after timeout

Tags: python, regex, windows

Is there a OS-independent or Windows-specific way to stop a regex search after a given amount of time or on user request?

My program provides text editing functionality with regex searching. If a user enters a pathological regex pattern searching may need too much time. It would be good to stop the search at user request or at least after a given timeout.

I found solutions for Linux/Unix using `signal.alarm()` but this function isn't supported on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, do the search on a separate thread, if the time expires or cancelled, terminate the thread?

Comment: I think the GIL prevents the monitor thread from getting a chance to stop the search thread while the search is running.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python it is unsafe and officially unsupported to terminate a thread

Comment: @user2357112 Good thing I don't really program in python, although IronPython doesn't have a GIL to cause such issues.